# Assigning a negative byte to itself

Tags: java, byte, signed, primitive-types, type-mismatch

I'm facing this line of code.

```
byte b='b';
b=-b;
```

So b is now 98. But now the second line gives a type mismatch error(cannot convert from int to byte).
Why is that? I read around, heard a lot of "all bytes are signed" but I still don't get it.
A thorough answer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which programming language? (`byte` is unsigned in most, so you are probably experiencing a type promotion).

Comment: `byte b = 'b'` is not a valid Java local or field declaration.

Comment: I sort of wanna understand this issue, so if answers could be informative and at the same time not very complicated that would be amazing guys.

Comment: Well it works. If I comment out b= -b and print b the value is 98

Comment: Thank you all for the informative replies. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, it seems puzzling:

```
b = 'b';
```

Takes a wider type `char` which takes 2 bytes in memory, and puts it into a single byte. This shouldn't work. But it does.

```
b = -b;
```

Takes a negative byte and puts it in a byte. This should work, but it doesn't.

The reason for the success of `b = 'b'` is actually the fact that `'b'` is a constant expression. As such, the compiler identifies that it does not overflow a single byte, and therefore allows the assignment. If, instead of that, you had written:

```
char c = 'b';
byte b = c;
```

this would have failed, because `c` is no longer a constant expression.

The reason that the second assignment failed has already been explained to you in other answers. As soon as you apply the `-` operator to a byte, the result is an `int`. Once that happens, again, you can't put it in a byte because an `int` takes 4 bytes. But you can cast it.

Answer (score 2):

The unary minus widens the operand to `int`. From the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.1):

> **15.15.4. Unary Minus Operator `-`**
>
> Unary numeric promotion (§5.6.1) is performed on the operand.
>
> **5.6.1. Unary Numeric Promotion**
>
> Some operators apply unary numeric promotion to a single operand, which must produce a value of a numeric type:
>
> - ...
> - Otherwise, if the operand is of compile-time type `byte`, `short`, or `char`, it is promoted to a value of type `int` by a widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2).

To assign the result back to `b`, you need to explicitly cast it to `byte`:

```
    b = (byte)-b;
```

Answer (score 1):

`The unary - operator may perform a type conversion. If the type of the operand is byte, short, or char, the operation converts the operand to an int before computing the value's arithmetic negation and producing an int value`

Taken from here: http://oponet.stsci.edu/web/documentation/Java%20Reference%20Library%201.02/langref/ch04_04.htm

Answer (score -2):

A byte in Java is an unsigned integer type with a valid value range of 0 to 255.  When you make the negation assignment, e.g. b=-b, the right hand side is converted to an integer in order for the negation to occur.

So, after that conversion, you are assigning a signed integer, which can have values from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647, to a variable that can only hold values from 0 to 255.  The compiler is telling you that you will lose precision by making this assignment, since it will have to discard bits to coerce the number into the 0 to 255 range.

Comment: [Primitive Data Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)